# SSRS, Visual Studio, Sorting on Category group on series group

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table with three different columns: FaultLevel1, FaultLevel2 and Quantity. This columns are extracted after filtering parameters from other columns, but graph uses these three columns.

So, the graph looks like a waterfall graph (Range Column graph), and in

1. Category Groups: FaultLevel1;
2. Series Groups: FaultLevel2;
3. Values:Sum(Quantity).

Basically, the issue is in sorting, because first I need to sort by FL1 (quantity), and then by FL2 (quantity). But when it generates, it looks like a waterfall, but the FL2 values with high to low come after each other, whereas, it should come in such an order that all quantities of FL2 on each FL1.

So, the question is how can I put sorting for FL2, that is sorts on Sum(Quantity) of FL1, not quantity of FL2.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, the chart has same structure as matrix instead of table.

Category: Row Group

Series: Column Group

Values: Value

If your data are just the three columns in a table, they are under same level. You should not make data in tabilx without column group rendered in a chart with series. Otherwise, it will look like a waterfall as your scenario.